# apply function with if

Tags: r, plyr

I am struggling to implement a simple instruction on one column of my df.

I have a long column with many of the entries as #VALUE and a few with legitimate numbers. What I would like to do is change the "#VALUE" entries to na's to then use the function na.locf to fill in the actual numbers into all of those rows.

I have tried several iterations and have had no luck, as seen below. Does anyone know of a nice solution for this? Thank you!

**Attempt 1:**

```
y2005[,24]=apply(y2005[24],2, function(x) if(x=="#VALUE") {x=NA})
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
spreadfind=function(x) {
 if(x=="#VALUE")
   return(NA)}

y2005$spread=sapply(y2005$spread,spreadfind)
```

Both of these would ideally be followed by:

```
y2005$spread=na.locf(y2005$spread,fromLast=FALSE)
```

Comment: `df[ df=="#VALUE" ] <- NA`, also you can define `na.string` when reading in the data.

Comment: if the column is `character`, as.numeric(y2005[,24])# should return NA for all non-numeric entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your data frame `y2005` and the column you are referring to the 24th one? To replace "#VALUE" with `NA`, you just need to do

```
y2005[, 24][y2005[, 24] == "#VALUE"] <- NA
```